# How to Change the Value of an Input Field Back off Focus

Tags: javascript, input, text, window, onfocus

I have managed to change the text value of the input field onfocus to nothing, but I can't work out how to get it to change back on the onclick of anywhere else on the webpage
HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="this is value" id="text">
```

JS:

```
 document.getElementById("text").onfocus = function() {
            var value = "on"
            if (value==="on") {
            document.getElementById("text").value=""
                value="off"
            } else {
                document.getElementById("text").value="this is value"
                value="on"
            }
            window.onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("text").value="this is value"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you right. But I don't think you need this much-complicated stuff here, you can just simply use [`placeholder`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj8l5T-zuXqAhUDd98KHZO9AnUQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTML%2FElement%2Finput&usg=AOvVaw3u1zyIbT14z2CbRisJaMP4). Then you can clear it on the input focus with [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) event and again show it with [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event if you like.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="this is value" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'this is value'" id="text">
```

Otherwise, you can simply create the placeholder and leave it be till the user fill the input with their desired value.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="this is value" id="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what are you trying, but I think you maybe need a `blur` event.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("text");
var value = "on";

input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  if (value == "on") {
    input.value = "";
    value = "off";
  }
  else {
    text.value = "this is value";
    value = "on";
  }
});

input.addEventListener("blur", function () {
  input.value = "this is value";
  value = "on";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="this is value" id="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to the `onfocus` event there is the `onblur` event. The second one will be called, when something else was liked and the input losses the focus. Checkout this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp#:%7E:text=The%20onfocus%20event%20occurs%20when,%3E%2C%20and%20.&text=However%2C%20you%20can%20achieve%20this,method%20for%20the%20onfocus%20event.).

The following code should fulfill your requirement:

```
 document.getElementById("text").onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("text").value=""
 }
document.getElementById("text").onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("text").value="this is value"
}
```